# What is a "longstop"? (British, I think)

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english

I've come across this word applied to God in a book by Julian Barnes but I don't understand it.

> And perhaps God doesn't mind being addressed only in emergency. It may
>   seem to bystanders that any sensible deity ought to be offended by
>   such spotty, self-interested attention.
>   But He might view things differently. He might, modestly, not want to
>   be a daily, occluding presence in our lives. He might enjoy being a
>   breakdown specialist, an insurance company, a **longstop**.
>
> [Julian Barnes. *Nothing to Be Frightened Of*](https://books.google.it/books?id=fquz3K4qnpQC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=But%20He%20might%20view%20things%20differently.%20He%20might,%20modestly,%20not%20want%20to%20be%20a%20daily,%20occluding%20presence%20in%20our%20lives.%20He%20might%20enjoy%20being%20a%20breakdown%20specialist,%20an%20insurance%20company,%20a%20longstop.%20Julian%20Barnes.%20Nothing%20to%20Fear&source=bl&ots=X9wKxpNwfE&sig=y_z4MMMAG20pAyHZbD7ydcNxMwY&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_-YGVg8jNAhVFFiwKHfJtDMUQ6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=But%20He%20might%20view%20things%20differently.%20He%20might%2C%20modestly%2C%20not%20want%20to%20be%20a%20daily%2C%20occluding%20presence%20in%20our%20lives.%20He%20might%20enjoy%20being%20a%20breakdown%20specialist%2C%20an%20insurance%20company%2C%20a%20longstop.%20Julian%20Barnes.%20Nothing%20to%20Fear&f=false)

I've found the phrase *longstop* or *long-stop* or *long stop date*, but it doesn't seem to make sense in the text. References to *longstop* as a single word without hyphen appear almost only in .uk domain, so I think is British English. I also found this explanation in a book:

> In cricket a 'longstop' is a fielder who is placed a few yards
>   directly behind the wicketkeeper so that if the wicketkeeper fails to
>   stop the ball then the long-stop is there to provide cover for the
>   wicketkeeper and stop the ball reaching the boundary. The principle in
>   *Hastings-Bass* used to have this role in case trustees caused a loss in trust in the exercise of their powers (like the ball getting past
>   the wicketkeeper) by simply having the exercise of those powers
>   reversed after the event.
>
> [Alastair Hudson. *Equity and Trusts*](https://books.google.es/books?id=-ODpAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT807&lpg=PT807&dq=%22a+longstop+is%22+cricket&source=bl&ots=2-ockvIs9Q&sig=_UJJ00MFC46CxDDWYwgvUozW0wc&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinteaC8cfNAhUE1xQKHUVwAKEQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

But I don't fully grasp it. What is the *longstop* Barnes is referring to? Would you provide any examples or synonyms?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fielding_(cricket)#Other_positions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that "longstop" is referring to the cricket position, and that makes sense in context:  the job of the longstop is to act as **backup for the wicket keeper**.

If everything goes according to plan, they will never have to do anything - the wicket keeper will stop the ball.  But, sometimes, due to a mistake by the wicket keeper, or an unexpected bounce, etc, the ball will get past the wicket keeper and the longstop will step in to stop the ball instead.

In this sense, the longstop position is a **form of insurance** - like a breakdown specialist, and an insurance company (the other examples) - you only need them when things go wrong, or not as planned, but when you need them you are glad that they're there.

The writer is saying that God might be like this - that He only intervenes in emergencies, perhaps to save someone from dying in an accident, or when someone is very depressed, etc.

Comment: My native language is not English so I am not sure whether **insurance** would be suitable for a person. I thought it's only applied to things. I've found this: [""The fact that someone as powerful as an ombudsman is behind any complaint as a longstop is a great advantage."](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld199697/ldhansrd/vo970311/text/70311-24.htm). Would **insurance** be a good synonym in this sentence? What another word could you use?

Comment: "backup" is the best single-word synonym for "longstop" i think. First definition, here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/backup

Comment: You could describe a person as "a form of insurance" - form meaning "type" in this sense.

Comment: OK. I don't know why I thought it had a distinctive meaning in certain contexts (legal ones or so) as an idiom in the UK. Unless a British person correct us, I think you're right.

Comment: I'm British, and I've never encountered it before.  I think it's just a sporting metaphor, and it's not widely used.

Comment: A fielding position behind the wicketkeeper really hasn't been used for a very, very long time in cricket; even the idea really only continues in a few expressions.

Comment: @Glen_b  While no professional cricket team would use the position, it is still occasionally used by bad amateur teams. Since using the name 'longstop' implies that the captain thinks poorly of both his bowlers' accuracy and his wicketkeeper's skill, it would tend to get called a 'very fine leg' or 'very fine third man'.

Comment: The word "backstop" has also been used for backup/insurance, in sense of "if something gets past the person/device/procedure that is meant to handle it, there is this semi-emergency contingency handler that will deal with the problem".

Comment: @Glen_b: longstop position is still occasionally used, but it is considered somewhat unorthodox these days. Last time I actually saw it was a test match in South Africa maybe 15 years ago (I forget exactly); I seem to recall that the main aim of using it then was to intimidate the batsman (ie he thinks the bowler might be about to bowl an extra-fast ball that would be difficult even for the wicket keeper). But normally you're right; one wouldn't use the position often because it uses up a fielder who would probably be better placed elsewhere.

Comment: @user73481 So it seems like a backstop is what gets hit when even the longstop missed it? ;)

Comment: Wikipedia lists it under "Other positions" on the [Fielding (cricket)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fielding_(cricket)#Other_positions) page, as two words.

Comment: @Glen_b I'm no sportsman: I don't watch cricket, & haven't played cricket since I was at school in the 1960s - but I knew immediately what a "longstop" referred to.  So it can't be that rare a usage.

Comment: @TrevorD I watch quite a bit of cricket. It might occasionally come up (especially as a joke) in a backyard game or something at a similar level, and it is sometimes used as an expression more widely, but the position isn't used in cricket matches where any level of skill is needed. Even if the wicketkeeper were injured and replaced with a less competent player such that some form of backup was considered, the position employed would be slightly to one side or the other, such as deepish third man or a deep fine leg (so the term longstop would still not be used for the position), ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... but even then it's very rare to do it because you must lose a fielder from somewhere to fill that place, leaving a potentially important gap. Losing a few runs there is generally better. ... note that I wasn't saying people never use the word, only that the position itself isn't used in cricket matches that require real skill.

Comment: @Glen_b Apologies & thanks for the response. I had understood what you were saying about current usage & playing positions in cricket - and sorry if I implied otherwise. I had - obviously wrongly - thought that you were saying that the word itself was very rare. It's obviously not common - and maybe it's more rare these days that I realised: maybe I just know & recognise the word from 'my younger days'!